# How to download an external file (xl or pdf) from Tableau server when clicked on an image on the dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I need to provide a feature to download the file, stored on Amazon S3 bucket when the user clicks on an image displayed on the dashboard. This is for the Desktop as well as Server Edition.

I tried doing it through "Action" but it's neither working on Desktop nor on the Server.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Agree! Thanks @halfer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Actions where you want to apply you can find it on worksheet as well as on dashboard

[image]

Select URL action

[image]

Choose Select on run action and set your link in URL

[image]

When you click on image it will open in new browser.